# how to add camera preview inside gameview (surface view)

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

Is that possible to add camera preview inside my gameview ?
I tried to add the camera preview inside the gameview this errors appear.

E/SurfaceHolder: Exception locking surface                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

It seem like something wrong with my gameloop
but i have no idea how to solve it.
Anyone know how to solve the problem?

My GameLoop

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {
public static final int MAX_FPS = 30;
private double averageFPS;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private GamePanel gamePanel;
private boolean running;
public static Canvas canvas;

public void setRunning(boolean running){
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel){
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long startTime;
    long timeMillis = 1000/MAX_FPS;
    long waitTime;
    int frameCount = 0;
    long totalTime = 0;
    long targetTime = 1000/MAX_FPS;

    while(running){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        canvas = null;

        try{
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            if (canvas != null){
                try{
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
        timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
        waitTime = targetTime - timeMillis;
        try{
            if(waitTime > 0 )
                this.sleep(waitTime);
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        frameCount++;
        if(frameCount == MAX_FPS){
            averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
            frameCount = 0;
            totalTime = 0;
            System.out.println(averageFPS);
        }
    }
}
```

}

My GameView

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private MainThread thread;

private ObstacleManager obstacleManager;

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public GamePanel(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    thread = new MainThread(mHolder, this);

    obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager(100, 100, Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try{
        //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
    }
    thread = new MainThread(holder, this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
        return;

    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
    }

    //now, recreate the camera preview
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = false;
    while(retry){
        try{
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        retry = false;
    }
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}

public void update(){
    obstacleManager.update();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    obstacleManager.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

My MainActivity

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

//declaring gameview
private GameView gameView;
private Camera mCamera;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;
private GamePanel gamePanel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
    Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;


    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open(0);//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (mCamera != null) {
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameView);
        gamePanel = new GamePanel(this, mCamera);
        frameLayout.addView(gamePanel);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same surface for both camera preview and canvas draw. You can create two surfaces, one next to the other, but don't even try to put one on top of the other, they will not keep the z-order reliably. The best approach is to switch the camera preview to SurfaceTexture, and use the same OpenGL context for drawing your game and camera preview.